# Selecting Objects in the graphic without having to select the layer first

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In previous versions of Photoshop, I was able to select (with my mouse) objects within a graphics, where I could click and then drag the object where I want to move it. Now I have to select the layer before I can drag the object. Is there a setting that I need to configure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while common design tools may be in use, this question is asking about software education, not design.

Answer (score 1):

When you select the Move Tool `V key` you will see in the option bar a check box `auto-select` and a drop down list next to it. Check the box, and put layer in the drop down list. Know, whenever you click on an element that was not locked, it is selected in your layers panel.

Comment: To expand on this answer, without enabling `auto-select`, you can simply CMD (CTRL) + Click on the object you want to select in your document (with the `Move Tool` active).  Unless the layers are in groups, then it will select the group.